# How to automatically update column in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a session_id column in users table and i set default as 0 and i want to make it automatically change to 1 when user succesfully login

**This the database picture**

[image: Database]

And for the controller and login model i use ion_auth library

You can see the controller here
[Controller Auth.php](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/3/controllers/Auth.php)

And the model 
[Ion auth model](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth/blob/3/models/Ion_auth_model.php)

And for the view i use this
**form_login.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Login-session</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/Parsley/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/Parsley/dist/parsley.min.js"></script>
  <!-- css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/all-css/login.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="login">
    <h4 style="text-align: center;">Login To Your Start</h4>
    <div id="infoMessage">
      <p><?php echo $message;?></p>
    </div>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>auth/login"  method="post" class="demo-form" data-parsley-validate="">
      <label>email or username</label>
      <input type="email" name="identity"  id="exampleInputEmail1" data-parsley-trigger="changes" required="">
      <label>password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" data-parsley-length="[8, 16]" data-parsley-group="block2">
      <button type="submit" value="Login" class="btnSubmit validate">Login</button>
    </form>

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $('.demo-form').parsley().on('form:validate', function (formInstance) {
    var ok = formInstance.isValid({group: 'block1', force: true}) || formInstance.isValid({group: 'block2', force: true});
    $('.invalid-form-error-message')
      .html(ok ? '' : 'You must correctly fill *at least one of these two blocks!')
      .toggleClass('filled', !ok);
    if (!ok)
      formInstance.validationResult = false;
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have already given you an [algorithm](https://justpaste.it/rifa1) to implement this yesterday here on stackoverflow.

Comment: If any stack**overflow** user tell me to write that algo as an answer, then I will do it, because this [algorithm](https://justpaste.it/rifa1) link is not a permanent link. It can be automatically remove any time.

Comment: What it  looks like this..? this is not finish yet                                                                    `if ($query->num_rows() !== 0)
  {
   $this->set($session_id);
  }`

Comment: `if ($query->num_rows() !== 0)` is for 'user-ID' and 'password' then check `session_id  == 0` in **database**. If equals to 0 then set `session_id = 1` in **database** and then login that user else give him alert meaasge that your account is already loggedin in another browser.

Comment: I have succeeded in making validation if **session_id** 1 then the user will not be able to log in but I am changing the database manually I have not been able to make **session_id** change automatically when the user successfully logged in

Comment: Okay no problem. but check that validation by trying  to login in different browser while you're already logged-in in your browser with the same account (userID and password). If you'r not able to login in different browser then it means my algo is working.

Comment: its worked thanks @Abhishek Kamal. I just need to add more code at login function **:)**

Comment: Yes, you just need to add logics for  **session_id** as described in algo or modify it according to your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ***Given below is an algorithm to implement what you have asked yesterday and today including this question***

### *Algorithm starts -*

#### **When user fills the user-ID and Password in login form -**

1. Check the *user-ID && password* both are correct.

   ```
    If both are correct then check `session_id == 0` in database

       If true then 

           set session_id = 1 in database and login that user.

       If false then 

           redirect back to home page or give him/her an alert message('you
           can't login now because your account is already logged in another
           browser').

           **Note :** You can also show the message as user's (which is already 
           loggedin) browser name, IP address, First loggedin time/date etc.
   ```
2. If both (user-ID and Password) are NOT correct then
        `show the error message('userID or Password is not correct').`
3. When User tries to logout then, the very first thing you must do that (**important**)

   ```
     Set session_id = 0 in database.

     then logout that user.
   ```

### *Algorithm ends -*

**What does this algorithm do ?**
If you already logged-in in a browser then you **can't login** again in different browser until you logged out from the original browser.